# Number not incrementing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to learn Javascript by creating a Quiz App like it's mentioned here: [Learn Javascript Properly](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/) I have trouble trying to do the more advanced quiz, I'm using Handlebars as my templating engine. I've stored the questions in an external JSON file, and the inputs are just a bunch of radio buttons.

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz Application</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="quiz">
    </div>
    <button id="next-question">Next Question</button>   
</div>

<!-- Templates -->
<script id="titleTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="quiz-question">{{ title }}</div>
</script>
<script id="choicesTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="choices">
        <form id="choicesForm">
                {{#each choices}}
                <div class="choice">
                    <input type="radio" name="choices" id="choice{{@index}}" value="{{ @index }}">
                    <label for="choice{{ @index }}" value="{{ @index }}">{{ this }}</label>
                </div> 
                {{/each}}
        </form>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've explained everything in the comments
**app.js**:

```
 "use strict";
var Render = {
    question: function(questions, currentIndex) {
        var titleTemplate   = Handlebars.compile($("#titleTemplate").html());
        var choicesTemplate  = Handlebars.compile($("#choicesTemplate").html());
        var currentQuestion = questions[currentIndex];
        Render.title(titleTemplate, currentQuestion);
        Render.choices(choicesTemplate, currentQuestion);
    },
    title: function(titleTemplate, currentQuestion) {
        $("#quiz").html(titleTemplate(currentQuestion));
    },
    choices: function(choicesTemplate, currentQuestion) {
        $('#quiz-question').append(choicesTemplate(currentQuestion));
    },
};

var Quiz = {
    // Tracks the current questions
    currentIndex: 0,

    // The number of the correct answers
    // I want to increment this when the user 
    // answers the correct question, for some reason it doesn't increment.
    correctAnswers: 0,

    // I first call this method to get the questions from JSON file
    // since you can no longer have synchronous requests
    getQuestions: function() {
        $.getJSON('questions.json', Quiz.start);
    },
    // Starts the quiz
    start: function(questions) {
        // Check if the user is passed the last question
        // in this case, if 6 > 5
        if(Quiz.currentIndex + 1 > questions.length) {
            Quiz.displayFinalScore(questions);
        } else {
            // Render the next question using the currentIndex
            Render.question(questions, Quiz.currentIndex);
            Quiz.handleQuestion(questions);       
        }
    },

    handleQuestion: function(questions) {
        // Get's the correct answer from the JSON
        var correctAnswer = questions[Quiz.currentIndex].correctAnswer;
        // Check if the radio button is checked
        if($("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm") == correctAnswer) {
            // This doesn't increment like it suppose to
            // It still stays at 0.
            Quiz.correctAnswers +=  1;
        }

        // Increment the index to change to the next question
        Quiz.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    displayFinalScore: function(questions) {
        // Simple console log
        console.log("You have scored: " + Quiz.correctAnswers + " out of " + questions.length);
    }
};

$(function() {
    Quiz.getQuestions();    
    $("#next-question").on("click", Quiz.getQuestions);
})
```

As you can see I've explained in the comments, The problem is in incrementing the `correctAnswers` for some reason it doesn't get to the point where it compares both of the variables even if I choose the correct answer from the radio buttons.

**questions.json**:

```
[
    {
        "title":"When did the programming language C++ came out?",
        "choices":[
            1997,
            1995,
            2000,
            1998
        ],
        "correctAnswer":3
    },
    {
        "title":"When Node.js came out?",
        "choices":[
            2010,
            2011,
            2009,
            2006
        ],
        "correctAnswer":2
    },
    {
        "title":"What brand of laptop do I have?",
        "choices":[
            "HP",
            "Acer",
            "Dell",
            "Lenovo"
        ],
        "correctAnswer":0
    },
    {
        "title":"How old am I?",
        "choices":[
            12,
            20,
            9,
            16
        ],
        "correctAnswer":3
    },
    {
        "title":"How old is Google?",
        "choices":[
            12,
            20,
            18,
            16
        ],
        "correctAnswer":2
    }
]
```

Comment: parse it to int or to float to increment

Comment: I did that too, still it doesn't work.

Comment: can you create a simple demo that show your problem?

Comment: check what this evaluates to: $("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm") == correctAnswer. It could be false so it won't hit the increment section

Comment: maybe your problem is in compare part ! $("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm") == correctAnswer ! you are comparing an jquery Object to correctAnswer which I think is a text ! you can get .html() or .text() from your selector and then compare it using === not ==;

Comment: may be `correctAnswers` is set to zero every time when you call that function.

Comment: @MehdiMaghrooni I've compared it with .val() too, still it returns false when I compare both of them.

Comment: Have you tried `++` instead of `+=`?  So, just `Quiz.correctAnswers++`

Comment: I've tried `++` instead of `+=`, I even tried `Quiz.correctAnswers = Quiz.correctAnswers + 1`.

Comment: Have you tried without the if statement? If it increments without the if statement, then the problem is the conditions, and you can focus on that instead of looking other places.

Comment: It's in the if conditions, I'm pretty sure it's from the `$("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm") `.

Comment: Try to check each state and value(`val()` ,etc) of the `$("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm")` and `correctAnswer` using `console.log()` before your `if` condition; see what happens to the value of them in different selection options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code and they are:

- In the `start` function you should change `if` condition expression to match array indexes, which in JavaScript are starting from `0` and the last element of array have index `questions.length - 1`.
- In the `start` function you first render new question and then query DOM for selected element, which is already destroyed at this phase. So you need to first `handleQuestion` and only then render new one.
- I also moved `currentIndex` increment code to the last step (after render)
- Since `handleQuestion` should not be executed at the first render, I added this exotic `Quiz.currentIndex && Quiz.handleQuestion(questions);`, which actually means: "If `currentIndex` is 0, which in boolean expressions transforms to `false`, don't run the right part of boolean condition, which is `Quiz.handleQuestion(questions)`".
- To fetch a numeric value of selected input, you should use `parseInt($("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm").val(), 10)`

The resulting code should look like this:

**JavaScript**

```
// Starts the quiz
start: function(questions) {
    // Check if the user is passed the last question
    // in this case, if 5 >= 5
    if(Quiz.currentIndex >= questions.length) {
        Quiz.displayFinalScore(questions);
    } else {
        Quiz.currentIndex && Quiz.handleQuestion(questions);
        // Render the next question using the currentIndex
        Render.question(questions, Quiz.currentIndex++);
    }
},

handleQuestion: function(questions) {
    // Get's the correct answer from the JSON
    var correctAnswer = questions[Quiz.currentIndex-1].correctAnswer;
    // Check if the radio button is checked
    if(parseInt($("input[name=choices]:checked", "#choicesForm").val(), 10) === correctAnswer) {
        // This doesn't increment like it suppose to
        // It still stays at 0.
        Quiz.correctAnswers +=  1;
    }
}
```

**Live Demo**

https://plnkr.co/edit/03IGvb6IZiw6QbziUpw6?p=preview

Comment: Nice answer, but it still doesn't count the last answer. So even if I answer all of the questions correctly, the result would be 4 out of 5.

But still, you solved most of the problems, thank you!